# How do I zoom without a trackpad in Xcode Instruments Time Profiler?

Tags: macos, xcode, zoom, instruments

When using Xcode Instruments Time Profiler on my MacBook, I'm able to pinch to zoom in on the CPU measurements in the Swim-lane. However I cannot figure out how to do the equivalent on my iMac with no trackpad.

[image: Xcode Swim-lane screenshot]

How can I zoom in on a Swim-lane without a trackpad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your mouse has a wheel or touch - hold the option key and then use the scroll wheel / scroll gesture or control.

If you don't have that - you'll need to add a mouse with a wheel or add a trackpad to the iMac.

Comment: perfect, thank you. I figured out the option click drag to zoom but failed to try using the magic mouse 'wheel' gesture. Thank you!

Comment: I had to break out a mouse to test this :-)